# Realm Error io.realm.Realm.getDefaultMediator

Tags: android, realm

Ive just recently released an application and checking crasalytics over the last couple of days and ive had a number of crashes relating to this error io.realm.Realm.getDefaultMediator. It seems to crash when i get the instance of realm. Ive pasted the stack trace below.

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
       at com.electropages.mobile.classes.AlertBackgroundService.getAllReminders(AlertBackgroundService.java:57)
       at com.electropages.mobile.classes.AlertBackgroundService.onHandleIntent(AlertBackgroundService.java:52)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: Could not find io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator
       at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultMediator(Realm.java:256)
       at io.realm.Realm.<clinit>(Realm.java:165)
       at com.electropages.mobile.classes.AlertBackgroundService.getAllReminders(AlertBackgroundService.java:57)
       at com.electropages.mobile.classes.AlertBackgroundService.onHandleIntent(AlertBackgroundService.java:52)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator
       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
       at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultMediator(Realm.java:251)
       at io.realm.Realm.<clinit>(Realm.java:165)
       at com.electropages.mobile.classes.AlertBackgroundService.getAllReminders(AlertBackgroundService.java:57)
       at com.electropages.mobile.classes.AlertBackgroundService.onHandleIntent(AlertBackgroundService.java:52)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/realm/DefaultRealmModuleMediator
       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
       at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultMediator(Realm.java:251)
       at io.realm.Realm.<clinit>(Realm.java:165)
       at com.electropages.mobile.classes.AlertBackgroundService.getAllReminders(AlertBackgroundService.java:57)
       at com.electropages.mobile.classes.AlertBackgroundService.onHandleIntent(AlertBackgroundService.java:52)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.electropages.mobile-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.electropages.mobile-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Class.java)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:251)
       at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:216)
       at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultMediator(Realm.java:251)
       at io.realm.Realm.<clinit>(Realm.java:165)
       at com.electropages.mobile.classes.AlertBackgroundService.getAllReminders(AlertBackgroundService.java:57)
       at com.electropages.mobile.classes.AlertBackgroundService.onHandleIntent(AlertBackgroundService.java:52)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Based on the stacktrace and based on another crash we were having, i believe it may be something to do with MultiDex being enabled. The crashes were only appearing on Android 4. devices. However, if someone could just clarify it for me that would be great.

Just in case. Another issue that has been occuring is this one. Not sure if there linked as its happening on android 5 devices.

```
Fatal Exception: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: The SavedPart class is missing from the schema for this Realm.
       at io.realm.SavedPartRealmProxy.validateTable(SavedPartRealmProxy.java:129)
       at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.validateTable(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:61)
       at io.realm.Realm.initializeRealm(Realm.java:553)
       at io.realm.Realm.createAndValidate(Realm.java:516)
       at io.realm.Realm.create(Realm.java:471)
       at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:389)
       at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:351)
       at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:332)
       at com.electropages.mobile.classes.AlertBackgroundService.getAllReminders(AlertBackgroundService.java:57)
       at com.electropages.mobile.classes.AlertBackgroundService.onHandleIntent(AlertBackgroundService.java:52)
       at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Realm goes through all the proxy classes for your model classes when opening the Realm the first time. DefaultRealmModuleMediator coordinates that and is the main class for controlling the schema for the Realm. I haven't heard of others having problems with MultiDex. Do you use ProGuard?

Comment: Proguard isnt currently enabled on this beta version. Is there anything else i can supply you which may help?

Comment: Ive just added another crash log to the answer, Not sure if there connected as there happening on different devices. However if it helps then great

Comment: Is that happening on clean installs or when overriding a old one? The message means that your `SavedPart` class cannot be found in the Realm file itself, and that should only happen if you are opening an old file.

Comment: I believe its old one, When the user gets my realm class it checks for the Migration exception and deletes the database. So at the point that this crashes the database should have been deleted.

Comment: We have a method called `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` on RealmConfiguration. Are you using that or doing your own detection?

Comment: Moving the discussion here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1794 is probably easier :)